# Is Bayes Theorem needed? Binary Signal Prosessing

Tags: probability

A binary communication channel carries two types of data $0$ and $1$. Due to disturbance sometimes data flipped i.e sent $0$ received as $1$ and sent $1$ received as $0$. For a given channel assume probability of $0.80$ that a sent $0$ received as $0$  and $0.75$ that a sent $1$ received as $1$. Let $0$ be transmitted with probability $0.40$, if the signal sent.

1. What is the probability that $0$ was received?
2. Determine the prob that $1$ transmitted given that $0$ was received.
3. Finally $0$ transmitted given that $0$ was received.

Here is what I did:

$0$  can be received in $2$ ways when actually $0$ was sent and also $1$ was sent. As probability of sending $0$ is $.40$ so $0.40\times 0.80+ 0.25\times 0.60=0.47$?

If my this approach is correct, then I think I can solve the othe two. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Your first answer is correct. so what do you think about 2 and 3?

Comment: For 2 & 3 use Bayes' Th.